# Unable to abstract the CSF Default Export with a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I want to abstract the CSF default export object for Storybook, like below:

**metaFunction.js**

```js
export const getMeta = (title, component) => ({
  title: `Example/${title}`,
  component: component,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
  },
});
```

**Button.stories.js:**

```js
import { Button } from './Button';
import { getMeta } from './metaFunction';

// This works 
// const meta = {
//   title: 'Example/Button',
//   component: Button,
//   tags: ['autodocs'],
//   argTypes: {
//     backgroundColor: { control: 'color' },
//   },
// };

// This doesn't 
const meta = getMeta('Button', Button);

export default meta;

export const Primary = {
  args: {
    primary: true,
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Secondary = {
  args: {
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Large = {
  args: {
    size: 'large',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};

export const Small = {
  args: {
    size: 'small',
    label: 'Button',
  },
};
```

The problem is that when I use the `getMeta` function, Storybook crashes with the error "CSF: missing default export". It seems like I must declare an object and cannot abstract it at all, or even use a spread object inside the initial meta object.

Is there any way to abstract the CSF default export object with a function?

**To Reproduce**:

Go to [this repo and the function_debug branch](https://github.com/jimmy-e/storybook-fn-debug/tree/function_debug), run `npm install` and then `npm run storybook`.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop here because it looks like you also [opened a bug](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21703) in the [Storybook GitHub](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook) that [got an answer](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/21703#issuecomment-1517178300)...

[@jeshio is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76109337/22973498) in demonstrating the use of the spread operator on the `getMeta` invocation and the explicit assignment of the `title` property to the  `default` export because Storybook v7 uses static code analysis to read the `title` property and generate the navigation on the left sidebar. Since static code analysis can't invoke a function, this is the only way to provide SB7 access to that required property.

Other properties, like `tags`, also need to be declared on the `default` export so they can they be picked up via static code analysis.

However! There's still value in abstraction. If you'd like to generate an extended meta to provide a common set of arg controls on your components (like a control for theming), you can extend the default meta and use it like so...

```js
/* Theming.ts */

import { ArgTypes, Meta } from '@storybook/react';

/**
 * Returns the argType used to add a theme control to a Storybook story
 */
function getThemeArgTypes(): ArgTypes {
  return {
    'data-theme': {
      control: { type: 'select' },
      options: ['none', 'light', 'dark'],
      mapping: {
        none: null,
        light: 'light',
        dark: 'dark',
      },
    },
  };
}

/**
 * Returns a Storybook meta object with an additional theme control
 */
export function getThemeableMeta<T>(meta: Meta<T>) {
  return {
    ...meta,
    argTypes: {
      ...meta.argTypes,
      ...getThemeArgTypes(),
    },
  };
}
```

```js
/* ThemeableComponent.stories.ts */

import { getThemeableMeta } from 'Theming.ts';

/**
 * Define extended component meta
 */
const meta = getThemeableMeta<typeof Component>({
  component: Component,
});

export default {
  title: 'Components/Component',
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  ...meta,
};
```

By following this approach, every set of component stories that you write by using the `getThemeableMeta` function will have a theme control without having to set global args via `.storybook/preview.ts`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
export default { ...getMeta('Button', Button), title: 'Button' }
```